# Unable to launch Appcelerator IDE?

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Followed Steps provided by [platform.appcelerator.com](http://platform.appcelerator.com) :

1. Account Created
2. Download **Appcelerator Studio IDE**
3. Installed Sucessfully
4. Launching by providing Username and Password
5. Error Occurred and unable to lanunch , Here is screenshot:

[image]

Kindly help to solve this issue . Any help is highy appreciated.

Comment: I hope your organization's firewall might be blocking the appcelerator's update site url which could be the reason behind this error. Try to raise an exception for these url's and try again

Comment: It is launching , without opening Appcelerator studio ide how can i handle exception ? I just provide username and password and then try to launch bug above error occurs. Kindly suggest ?

Comment: Talk to your SysAdmin and raise a firewall exception for that URL

Comment: Okey Thanks let  me chck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - Appcelerator Studio is unable to install latest appc CLI due to proxy/network configuration issues.

To identify the root cause.

Open a terminal and run the below command.

> appc use latest

Is it the same error which you've reported? If yes, verify proxy configuration

> appc config get proxyServer

Does it show any configured proxy?  If yes, and it was set unintentionally, you can remove that by running the below command.

> appc config set proxyServer

This will nullify your proxy configuration.

If there is no proxy configured, still you are facing the issue. Then, your network firewall is not allowing to access Appcelerator Software Update site.

Contact your network admin to unblock it.